# Better Method for Latching data

Tags: c++

I have a requirement that 8 to 10 or so booleans need to be "Latched" for different amount of cycles, and then be reset individually. This code is called periodically every 250mS/cycle

Behavior:

Iterate through objects, if object is high, latch the value high for the remaining cycles. If object remaining cycles is 0, reset the value to low.

If object value is low do not act on object.

My design methodology is to create a structure with the following elements:

```
struct latchElement
{
       bool* value;
       int reqCycles;
       int currentCycle;
};
```

So I create an array of these latchElements:

```
latchElement boolData[8];
```

And now I have to individually assign each one of these boolData's to individual booleans. I'm just checking if this is the best way to do this?

I have a pointer that will be individually assigned to each boolean:

```
bool value1 = false;
bool value2 = false;
bool value3 = false;
bool value4 = false;
bool value5 = false;
bool value6 = false;
bool value7 = false;
bool value8 = false;
boolData[0].value = &value1;
boolData[1].value = &value2;
boolData[2].value = &value3;
boolData[3].value = &value4;
boolData[4].value = &value5;
boolData[5].value = &value6;
boolData[6].value = &value7;
boolData[7].value = &value8;
```

Then I run through a loop checking if the value is high, if it is I increment the currentCycle if it is less than ReqCycles. If the value is equal to ReqCycles I set the value to false, then I reset currentCycle to 0;

```
// NOTE: This loop is in a function that is called every 250mS
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
       if (*(boolData[i].value) == true)
       {
         if (boolData[i].currentCycle < boolData[i].reqCycles)
         {
             (boolData[i].currentCycle)++;
             cout << *(boolData[i].value) << endl;
         }             
         else
         {
             // Reset Back
             boolData[i].currentCycle = 0;
             *(boolData[i].value) = false;
         }          

       }
```

I'm just thinking is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: You know that one boolean needs just one bit, and there are 8 bits in a byte?

Comment: Isn't http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ a better place for this?